# Java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class Kotlin

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

[image: This always appear after changing the code I rebuild the project and everything goes fine]
Every time I change my code and run it, this appear and the second time I run the code, it doesn't appears, what is the cause of this bug ?

Comment: Please add code and error logs as text not as image!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

check project package name and add kotlin plugin & dependencies.

```
  apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

  classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
```

Comment: And make sure you have this plugin enabled in the module where your activity is defined ;)